# What is required to test RESTful services?

Tags: testing, rest, service

I need to test few RESTful services,

Not sure  what is the best tool to test and what else is required..

I did check SOAP UI but it requires WADL to test Restful services in SOAP UI however their is no WADL in my application.

Junit is one option I am aware looking much more simpler one..Kindly help 
Thanks in advance
Jithendra

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Postman (a google app) to build automated tests for RESTful webservices.  It's very easy to use and with the upgraded version you can build a lot of tests specific to your needs.